# ApexCharts Vue - Heatmap Chart - Zoom Timeline

Tags: java, vue.js, charts, vuetify.js, apexcharts

Is there a way to have a zoom feature in Heatmap chart from ApexCharts (VueJS)

```
<VueApexCharts v-bind:style="{ 'box-shadow':'0px 0px 2.3px 0px'}" width="350" height="220" type=heatmap :options="chartOptionsNew" :series="dataSeries"></VueApexCharts>
```

I'm able to get x axis zoom in and out but y axis values are not reflecting.[image]

```
chartOptionsNew: {
            chart: {
                stacked: false,
                zoom: {
                type: 'x',
                enabled: true,
                autoScaleYaxis: false,
                toolbar: {
                  autoSelected: 'zoom',
                  tools: { download: true, selection: true, zoom: true, zoomin: true, zoomout: true, pan: true, reset: true },
                }
              },
            }
```

Is this is possible in Heatmap charts from ApexCharts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set the zoom type to 'xy'

```
chartOptionsNew: {
    chart: {
        stacked: false,
        zoom: {
            type: 'xy', <--- this line
            enabled: true,
            autoScaleYaxis: false,
            toolbar: {
                autoSelected: 'zoom',
                tools: {
                    download: true,
                    selection: true,
                    zoom: true,
                    zoomin: true,
                    zoomout: true,
                    pan: true,
                    reset: true
                },
            }
        },
    }
```

> Note: Zooming will not be enabled for category axis, but only for charts having numeric axis. For eg., timeline charts.

Comment: Thank you @Simon but I tried that already, it is not helping.

Comment: did you try `autoScaleYaxis: true`?

Comment: is the y-axis actually numeric scale or categories?

Comment: It is category, non-numeric. Is it still possible? 
As x-axis is date time.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Okay, will try taking numeric series on y-axis.